# How to re-install command prompt in windows 10, if it's suddenly missing from the system?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

This morning, cmd.exe is missing from my computer (Windows 10), from the regular path C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe. Please don't advice on location check. My query is -

1. Is this a serious issue? Like some kind of malware attack?
2. Is it possible to get back / re-install command prompt (results from google / youtube are not helpful). I don't have a recovery partition.

Comment: Please list recent changes that were made. What is the path statement? What happens when you try typing "cmd" into run?

Comment: the Assist is much appreciated. NO changes were made. `cmd.exe` file is missing from the location. path was "C:/windows/system32/cmd.exe". many cmd related files are still in that folder, just not this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it could be evidence of a virus or malware
2. Yes you may be able to get back the command prompt by doing the following:

   1. Run powershell as admin
   2. Run the command `sfc /scannow`

It will repair missing or corrupted system files.